# How can I create a header location to folder based on which username is being used

Tags: php

I have a login form with a redirect to a menu page in the same directory that will link to other files in the same directory that are all shared by all the users in the database.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['password'] = $hash;
header("location:loginSuccess.php");
```

This works fine because loginSuccess.php is in the same directory as the login form.

But now I need the redirect to a particular sub-folder, depending on which user logged in. In other words, if user1 logs in, I want to redirect this user to /user1.loginSuccess.php, and if user2 logs in, I want to redirect this user to /user2/loginSuccess.php.

I tried the following:

```
header("location:/"<?php echo $username ?>"/loginSuccess.php");
```

I understand that this would translate to /user1/loginSuccess.php if user1 logged in, but got a message with **an unexpected ? on line 43**, which is the line with the above code.

I am self-taught in procedural php but relatively unfamiliar with object orientated php.

Any help and advise will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's wrong with `"location: /$username/loginSuccess.php"`?  https://php.net/language.types.string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is called string concatenation. Сhange your code

```
header("location:/"<?php echo $username ?>"/loginSuccess.php");
```

to

```
header('Location: /'.$username.'/loginSuccess.php');
```

and check the docs [String concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you concatenate a PHP string. You don't need the opening and closing tags because you already have a `<?php` tag before those lines. Just use

`header('Location: /'.$username.'/loginSuccess.php');`

String concatenation is done with a period.